# How to transfer a panel variant from one site to another?

Tags: 7, panels, features

Is there a way to do this with Features? I can't download and install any additional plugins to do this on this site.

Would anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Panels and panel variants can be exported using the Features module. If you are using the panel variant as a part of page manager the option to export variant is shown in the features UI under **page_manager_handlers**.

Check the screenshot below to see how sample variants of the node view (`node/%node`) page can be exported via features:

[image]